# Group by statement with summed and concatenated case statements?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm struggling with a query given to me by a co-worker that was partially finished. The error I get is "not a single-group group function" and I've tried various group-by statements, none of which seem to solve my issue

The 'unadjusted other' and 'adjustments other' seem to be the only non-aggregate pieces in the select statement, but when I try grouping by those, it doesn't seem to work.

I haven't yet gotten experience with concatenated aggregate fields so I'm in new territory and haven't been able to troubleshoot it quite yet.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sum(unadj_gross_for_other_brand+adjustments_for_other_brand) = 0 AND
                 sum(adjustments_for_other_brand+redist_gross) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END status,
       'Unadjusted Other='||unadj_gross_for_other_brand||
       ' Adjustments Other='||adjustments_for_other_brand||
       ' Adjusted Other='||sum(unadj_gross_for_other_brand+adjustments_for_other_brand) ||
       ' Redistributed='||sum(redist_gross) Note
FROM
(
select
1 as unadj_gross_for_other_brand,
0 as adjustments_for_other_brand,
0 as redist_gross
from dual
UNION
select
0 as unadj_gross_for_other_brand,
2 as adjustments_for_other_brand,
0 as redist_gross
from dual
UNION
select
0 as unadj_gross_for_other_brand,
0 as adjustments_for_other_brand,
3 as redist_gross
from dual
);
```

Expected results would look something like:

```
Status    Note   
1         Unadjusted Other = 1, Adjusted Other = 2, Adjusted Other = 3, Redistributed = 3
```

Or

```
Status    Note   
0         Unadjusted Other = 0, Adjusted Other = 0, Adjusted Other = 0, Redistributed = 0
```

Comment: You have a mix of aggregate and non-aggregate references for the same column. What are you expecting to happen and what output do you expect from this data? Please add expected results to your question as formatted text, not as a comment.

Comment: @AlexPoole I am looking to receive 2 columns as the result. First column is a 1 or 0 value indicating a pass or fail test, and the 2nd 'note' column will display the 3 values for each item selected in the subqueries unadj_gross_for_other_brand, adjustments_for_other_brand, and redist_gross. For example a results would read: 
Status: 1, Note: Unadjusted Other = 1, Adjusted Other = 2, Adjusted Other = 3, Redistributed = 3

Comment: Are you expecting one row of output for each row in the inline view (or you real tables in the real query)? Or just a single row - in which case do you just need to sum the first two values in the 'notes' too?

Comment: @AlexPoole - I updated expected results in my OP sorry about that. I am expecting only a single row of output either a 0 (pass) or 1 (fail) along with the values that led to this pass or failure. There are real tables in the query, I am just substituting with dual to simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mix of aggregate and non-aggregate references to the same values. The concatenation isn't really relevant; you'd have the same issue if you had all of the 'note' values as separate columns.

As you only want one row of output you just need to sum the first two references in your 'note' column, changing

```
       'Unadjusted Other='||unadj_gross_for_other_brand||
       ' Adjustments Other='||adjustments_for_other_brand||
```

to

```
       'Unadjusted Other='||sum(unadj_gross_for_other_brand)||
----------------------------^^^^                           ^
       ' Adjustments Other='||sum(adjustments_for_other_brand)||
------------------------------^^^^                           ^
```

or in situ:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sum(unadj_gross_for_other_brand+adjustments_for_other_brand) = 0 AND
                 sum(adjustments_for_other_brand+redist_gross) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END status,
       'Unadjusted Other='||sum(unadj_gross_for_other_brand)||
       ' Adjustments Other='||sum(adjustments_for_other_brand)||
       ' Adjusted Other='||sum(unadj_gross_for_other_brand+adjustments_for_other_brand) ||
       ' Redistributed='||sum(redist_gross) Note
FROM (
...
);

    STATUS NOTE                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
---------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 Unadjusted Other=1 Adjustments Other=2 Adjusted Other=3 Redistributed=3
```

All of the non-literal values in the result are now aggregates, so you don't need a group-by clause.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e4db25e1fc5c49182a1a889161275838) with two versions that give a zero status.

Answer (score 1):

the following should work

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sum(unadj_gross_for_other_brand+adjustments_for_other_brand) = 0 
             AND sum(adjustments_for_other_brand+redist_gross) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 
       END status
       ,'Unadjusted Other='||sum(unadj_gross_for_other_brand)
          ||' Adjustments Other='||sum(adjustments_for_other_brand)
          ||' Adjusted Other='||sum(unadj_gross_for_other_brand+adjustments_for_other_brand) 
          ||' Redistributed='||sum(redist_gross) as Note
  FROM (
        select
                1 as unadj_gross_for_other_brand,
                0 as adjustments_for_other_brand,
                0 as redist_gross
          from dual
        UNION
        select
                0 as unadj_gross_for_other_brand,
                2 as adjustments_for_other_brand,
                0 as redist_gross
          from dual
        UNION
        select
                0 as unadj_gross_for_other_brand,
                0 as adjustments_for_other_brand,
                3 as redist_gross
          from dual
        );
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2